# An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables: `<subjects>` and `<prerequisites>`. The primary key of prerequisite table is a composite key: `pr_subject_id` and `pr_prerequisite_subject_id` . They are both foreign keys from the `<subjects>` table. I can map the pr_subject_id in a association but i can't map the return trip (`pr_prerequisite_subject_id`). See image. How should i solve this?

**note**: When i made the associations in sql server it was fine but when i loaded the database in the entity framework, the entity framework dropped the prerequisite table because of this return trip association.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked around but i think this is a common problem with the Entity Framework. I found two workarounds [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/73e142ff-af73-4555-8823-90f82de335fa). Basically what i did was adding a third column er_id and let that be the primary key. Then to enforce that there will be no double of the other two columns i added a unique constraint.